# Is a password or passphrase needed with a keyfile backup to decrypt

Tags: passwords, disk-encryption

In my search for an encrypted NAS i have come across a few products that talk about backing up the encryption key and storing it in a safe location. My question is if this backed up keyfile is enough to decrypt the contents of an encrypted drive or is a password also required?

I am particularly interested in the Synology NAS DS216j, but general answers are also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common solution to mitigate the risk of password loss. Functionnally, it is equivalent to writing a secret (the password for decoding) down on a paper an then storing the paper in a physical safe: you can {login|unlock|decode} either by remembering the password or by opening the safe to get it back.

The risk is simply that if the place where you store your *secret* backup is not safe enough, you get a backdoor: anyone accessing the *safe place* can access the protected data.

That being said, this is common in corporate environment for full disk encryption: the IT support service setups the encrypted disk and keeps an image of the key sector that they store in their physical safe. They then give the computer to the user. The user can change its key at will and uses the disk normally. In case of a disaster (the user cannot unlock the disk because it has been severely injured, killed, or simply forgot its password), the organization can bring the disk back to the IT support service. They restore the saved key sector and regain access to the encrypted disk that can contain important files belonging to the organization.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, while you can generate a private key without a
passphrase/password, it is not advised to do so. However, in some situations, it
is necessary, depending on how the system architecture works.

The issue is that the private key is the key to the kingdom. If it does not have
a passphrase, then anyone who obtains the key can use it. If it does, then they
also need that passphrase to use it. However, if the key is part of some
automated authentication process, depending on how the system is implemented, it
may not be possible or it may not be convenient to have to enter a passphrase to
use the key. Often, there is a key agent involved whereby you are required to
enter the passphrase on first use and after that, the key agent will take care
of things (for example, on first connection).

It is possible that your NAS requires a private key without a passpharse due to
the underlying design/architecture. If this is the case and your concerned that
backing up your private key may not be secure enough, then the easy solution
would be to encrypt your backup with another key which does have a
password/passphrase.